# C++ alloc array of objects

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've got this issue with allocation of an array of some objects that I need to initialize with some constructor. Let me show what I mean:

```
ofstream* out = new ofstream[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "file" << i << ".txt";
    string str(ss.str());
    char *fileName = (char*)str.c_str();
    out[i] = ofstream(fileName); //Now, this is wrong
}
```

And I need some help on the `wrong` marked line. How do I allocate each member of that array?

And thank you for not pointing me to other posts (I looked on a lot before posting)

Comment: `out` is susceptible to a memory leak. Remember to call `delete[]` on out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `fileName` variable and use `out[i].open(str.c_str());` - and remember to `delete[] out;`

Comment: does `delete[]` also calls `close()` on each stream in my array?

Comment: @iuliux: delete[] will ensure the destructor of each stream is called - which closes it.

Comment: Cool. Then let your answer be the chosen one, though @Chris Kaminski also answered fine

Answer (score 5):

Here's the simplest solution to your problem.

```
out[i].open(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could optimize this, with removing `str` and `fileName`:
`out[ i ].open( ss.str().c_str() );`

Also, I'd recommend you yo use `std::vector` not to carry about memory allocation and deallocation.
`std::vector< std::ofstream >`

Comment: Well, I kind of read earlier why `ss.str().c_str()` doesn't work. The guys were saying that `ss.str` generates a temporary object.

Comment: Huh? It's strange O.o I don't see anything wrong with this - yes, `.str()` returns temp object, but what? It's still "live" when opening the file(stream).

Comment: I just ran this on Visual Studio 2010 and there are no even warnings, it works just fine :?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to call the constructor by the time you insert the element (maybe because your class doesn't have a default constructor), try placement new as described here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.5